# What's the alternative to pages/_app.js in app router in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router, app-router

I am just starting with NextJS and there is a new router called **app router**. Now I have some tutorials using `pages/_app.js` from the NextJS **page router**. So, what's the corresponding file for that in the **app router**?

Answer (score 7):

Inside `app` each folder represent a route segment. The very first folder i.e app itself represent the root route segment.

`app/layout.js` will now be the equivalent for `_app.js` in the new Next 13 app directory. Since, it is the one wrapping all route and sub routes of your whole app.

Answer (score 0):

there is not a corresponding file in `app` directory. this is what `pages/_app.js` used for

- Set up a global state
- Define global components
- Inject props into pages
- Add global CSS

I think if you create a context provider and use it in `RootLayout` like this

```
import NavBar from "./Navbar";
// you set the global state for auth
// you might create different contexts for different purpose
import AuthContext from "./AuthContext";
import "./global.css";
import "anyNpmModule.css";

export default function RootLayout({children }:{children:React.ReactNode}) 
 {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body>
        <main>
          <AuthContext>
            <main>
              <NavBar />
              {children}
            </main>
          </AuthContext>
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```